# JAXB and empty namespace when using @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to map a Map

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, jaxb

I'm trying to work with JAXB and @XmlJavaTypeAdaptor to map a Map during marshalling.  The only issue I'm having is that the "item" element that is used to contain each entry in the map is given a blank namespace.

Below is an example generated XML document that shows the issue:

```
<format xmlns="myNamespace">
    <data>
        <item xmlns:ns2="myNamespace" xmlns="">
            <ns2:key>Admin</ns2:key>
            <ns2:value>John</ns2:value>
        </item>
    </data>
</format>
```

I would like the fragment to look like this:

```
<format xmlns="myNamespace">
    <data>
        <item>
            <key>Admin</key>
            <value>John</value>
        </item>
    </data>
</format>
```

I've simplifed the real-life example to narrow it down to just this case.  Here is the class that is being marshalled:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "format")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
public final class Format {

    @XmlTransient
    private final Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    public Map<String, String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of XmlAdapter I am using:

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapElements[], Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public MapElements[] marshal(Map<String, String> stringStringMap) throws Exception {
        MapElements[] mapElements = new MapElements[stringStringMap.size()];
        int i = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: stringStringMap.entrySet()) {
            mapElements[i++] = new MapElements(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return mapElements;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(MapElements[] mapElements) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (MapElements mapElement : mapElements) {
            map.put(mapElement.key, mapElement.value);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

I set the package level information like so, this does help in that it ensures the namespace for all elements except the "item" elements have the namespace "myNamespace":

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "myNamespace", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.prystasj;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

I've tried every combination of annotation, e.g. @XmlElement(namespace="myNamespace"), I can think of throughout and there is no chance, so I think I'm missing something conceptual (or maybe even something rather trivial).

I'm using JAXB 2.2.2.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following for your `XmlAdapter`

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapAdapter.MapElements, Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public MapElements marshal(Map<String, String> stringStringMap) throws Exception {
        MapElements mapElements = new MapElements();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: stringStringMap.entrySet()) {
            mapElements.item.add(new MapElement(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return mapElements;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(MapElements mapElements) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (MapElement mapElement : mapElements.item) {
            map.put(mapElement.key, mapElement.value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static class MapElements {
        public List<MapElement> item = new ArrayList<MapElement>();
    }

    public static class MapElement {
        public String key;
        public String value;

        public MapElement() {
        }

        public MapElement(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This did the trick.  Could you maybe give some more info towards why it does indeed do the trick? Thanks again!

Comment: I am also interested in exactly why your code works Blaise. I have similar problems but can not get it to work. Could you please share some insights on this? Maybe even author of this question knows by know what was missing. Any help is appropriated.